# Symfony2 Form Widget Date

Tags: php, symfony, date, controller, widget

i have a problem with a widget date in a Symfony form, i have this code

```
->add('borndate', 'birthday', array(
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'attr'  => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
                'label' => 'user.birthday.label',
                'input' => 'string',
                'format' => 'yyyy.MM.dd',
                'empty_value' => array('year' => 'user.birthday.year', 'month' => 'user.birthday.month', 'day' => 'user.birthday.day'),
                'data' => '1950-01-01'
            ))
```

Now i have this type of format in my form: 
 **1950 - 01 - 01**  but i would this format **01 - 01- 1950** and print in a select the value of my db?
How can i do for solved this two problems?? 
Thanks and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: try to remove `'format' => 'yyyy.MM.dd'` that will/should takecare of your date format and then if you are using an entity with the form the date will auto populate when you are trying to edit (if i understand your question right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably:

```
/***/
'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy'
/***/
```

Comment: If i want put in a form input some data value from my db? How can i do for send a variable from my controller to buildform?? @scoolnico Thank for the answer

Comment: you want to display your form with specific data from your entity?

Comment: yes, i explain my situation.. This project was started by another developer and now there is the function for insert in a form the data from DB but in date input i can't update input with db value.. Thanks @scoolnico